# groovy type coercion with parentheses

Tags: groovy, coercion

I'm new to groovy and studying type coercion.

There's some strange operation when two bytes are added. As far as I know, groovy converts two bytes' addition as integer. But if there's parentheses, it still remains as Byte.

```
assert (Byte)1 + (Byte)2 instanceof Integer
assert ((Byte)1 + (Byte)2) instanceof Byte
```

I tested it on groovy 2.1.4 and can't understand the difference.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`(Byte)1 + (Byte)2` would result in a byte type, regardless of the parenthesis.

`(Byte)1 + (Byte)2 instanceof Integer` fails since it would first evaluate "2 instanceof Integer" to true and then try to cast true to Byte resulting in a cast exception.

UPDATE 1/1/2014: I took a closer look since it's a valid question as to why the assert doesn't produce a cast error too, here is what I found. Given this script:

```
(Byte)1+(Byte)2 instanceof Integer
assert (Byte)1+(Byte)2 instanceof Integer
```

According [to the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Phase+Guide), the Groovy compiler parses the script and creates an AST representation of the code based on a grammar. The first line is parsed into an `ExpressionStatement` (specifically a `CastExpression`) but the second line is parsed into an `AssertStatement`. An `AssertStatement` in Groovy's AST has a `BooleanExpression` child and it seems without clarifying parenthesis, this influences how it decides to parse the code... the two lines end up looking like this:

```
((1 + ((2) as Byte) instanceof Integer) as Byte)
assert ((1) as Byte) + ((2) as Byte) instanceof Integer : null
```

This is why the assert runs and ends up being true when the other results in a GroovyCastException. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not... I'm going to ask on the Groovy forum I think.

Comment: As @chrixian told, compiling `(Byte)1 + (Byte)2 instanceof Integer` failed.
But I still cannot understand why `assert (Byte)1+(Byte)2 instanceof Integer` runs without problem.

Comment: I updated my answer with more specifics. I'll update if I find out any more about why this behavior occurs.